# If $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is a basis for $T_P(S)$, give a parameterization whose partial derivatives agree with $v_1$ and $v_2$

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a regular surface $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, a point $p \in S$ and a basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ of the tangent plane $T_P(S)$, I want to prove the existence of a parameterization $\varphi: U \to S$ centered at $p$ for which $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial u}=v_1$ and $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial v}=v_2$.

I tried to give an argument in 
[Existence of a parameterization whose differential has columns $v_1,v_2 \in T_p(S)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903829/existence-of-a-parameterization-whose-differential-has-columns-v-1-v-2-in-t-p)

However, I'm not sure it is correct. May you help me, please?